# Call Azure Appservice API using App roles

Tags: azure

I am trying to implement Azure App service authorization using App Role(Application).

I have created two App registrations as provider and consumer.

The provider has a Role defined which is added as Permission scope in the consumer App.

I need help about how to authorize the consumer app to call an API in app service(.net core) which is using the provider app for authentication and authorization.

I am very new to Azure development and need support.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

BR

Comment: Can you share the following information,
1. Does your consumer app have a signed-in user when accessing the provider app, or it's a daemon app?
2. What is the permission type, Delegated or Application?

Comment: It will be a  daemon app. I tried adding [Authorize(Roles = "xxx")] and got "Sign In" message. The consumer will use client secret and hence Application permission.

Comment: I assume that you are using the client credential flow. It's probably easier for you to study this example, https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/2-Call-OwnApi In this example, the ToDoList-WebApi is the provider, and the Daemon-console is the consumer. Each needs to be initialised with the corresponding Azure app registration you have created. We can go through more details if you have the same use case.

Comment: I have used the same setup and getting "Sign in to your account" message. My authentication details    services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(configuration, "AzureAd")
                    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
                    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();     .

Comment: Will you be able to share your project? Also, always check the AzureAD configurations in your apps. Many parts can go wrong when setting up AAD Auth. When calling your provider API, can you capture the OAuth bearer token? You can decode that to see what's in the token, such as Roles.

Comment: I am having the bearer token generated with correct role. However when I try to call the provider URI , I get "Sign in to your account"